# HelloAR example is just searching for surfaces in linux

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine

I am following [HELLOAR](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart-android) tutorial on my Ubuntu laptop.

I selected PC,Max & Linux standalone as my platform and clicked Build and Run option.

[image: Linux platform]

The screen after execution is shown below:

[image: Searching for surfaces only]

What to do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

ARCore is targeting only mobile platforms so you can not build it for PC, Mac or Linux. You have to use either Android or iOS. But you can use an [emulator](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator) with Android Studio if you do not want to deal with devices.