# Running Augmented reality apps on Linux using emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, reference, augmented-reality

In continuation with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53267773/helloar-example-is-just-searching-for-surfaces-in-linux) question. I am asking this question.

I installed Android Studio. I installed Unity 3D. I followed tutorials of [Java-Android Studio](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart-android) and [Unity](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart-android). Nothing worked well because of the reason that they need the latest version of ARCore and neither my mobile nor emulator is compatible with it. I am exhausted searching for alternatives.

I didn't find any tutorial or guidance related to developing Augmented Reality Android apps. Please suggest me a reference that works on Ubuntu system without the need of the physical mobile, but with an emulator, if possible.

**Note**: Please provide a reference that is relatively easy to test small app initially so that I can proceed forward. I am saying this because of the reason that I am working from almost 3 months but didn't run a small AR app either in the emulator or in my mobile (Redmi Note - 4).

Comment: If your target device is not compatible with ARCore than you can't use it in any App. Did you try [Vuforia](https://www.vuforia.com)?

Comment: No, Vuforia isn't supported in Ubuntu as per my knowledge and my mobile or emulator is not arcore compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You should check [8thWall](https://8thwall.com/). It runs on almost all phones and it has [SLAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_localization_and_mapping) as well. You can not use it with emulator but it has an application called [XR Remote](https://docs.8thwall.com/#remote-overview) in which you can test your code without building for Android or iOS. Minimum requirement for Android is Android Kitkat (4.4) or higher and for iOS Minimum iOS 7.0 or later is required.

[image]

As the owner of the question stated 8thWall can not be used with Linux. As an alternative [ARToolKit] can be used. It is an open source AR framework. For more details you can refer [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8BSnf-ixIc) and [here](https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit-docs)

Comment: The tutorial is saying that it is intended for Windows or MAC laptop.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. The only solution i could find was [ARToolKit](https://github.com/artoolkit) which is open source and can be used on Linux. And you can use your [webcam](https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit-docs/blob/master/6_Unity/unity_about.md) as well. Good Luck!